# jquery descendant selector issue

Tags: jquery

Code below select the `<td>` in which I'd like to select an `<a>` tag. How can I get the `<a>` ?

```
var refresh_link = $(this).parent().next().next()
```

Markup: when I click TEXT LINK A I want to select TEXT LINK B

```
<tr>
        <!-- product id -->
        <td>6005</td>

        <!-- product name -->
        <td>            
        Bla bla text<br />
        </td>

        <!-- monthly or daily price -->
        <td>
        270.0&euro; / mois
        </td>

        <!-- quantity + hidden field with the rowid + hidden field with original price at pageload -->
        <td>    
        TEXT LINK A
        </td>

        <!-- rental duration -->
        <td>
        bla
        </td>

        <!-- refresh / update cart quantity or duration -->

        <td><a id="1" href='#'>bla</a></td>

        <!-- total price calculated -->
        <td class='price_tot'>
        TEXT LINK B
        </td>

        <!-- send to trash -->
        <td><a href='#'>trash</a></td>

    </tr>
```

Comment: I don't understand neither what you want to get, nor the HTML structure you are transversing... Please clarify.

Comment: showing the markup would be helpful.

Comment: When I click a link in a table cell, I want to select a link in another table cell 2 cols down in the same row.

Comment: Again, show an example of what you're trying to traverse and indicate where you're starting. People are clearly willing to help, but you have to put in some effort asking the question clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
 var refresh_link = $(this).parent().next().next().find('a');
```